# Move instances with an object proximity

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying basic proximity to move instances relative to the sphere.. But the instances move back towards the target, and I want them to stay where they were.

[image]

Comment: just check whether the direction points to or from the sphere. if it points to sphere, just multiply it with scale -1.

Comment: Do you mean you want them to stay where they were, after the sphere has moved away?

Comment: @RobinBetts the instances repel away from sphere initialy, but if push further in same direction, it comes back towards its original position. As seen in image, some instances are inside the sphere.

Comment: You've told us what they do, but (forgive me) I still don't get what you _want_.

Comment: @RobinBetts excuse me for that... I exactly want what you said.. i want them to stay at offset position after the sphere is moved.

Comment: If an element needs to know its history, we're into simulation? This problem  is very similar to the [Demo File](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/) illustrating the  _Index of Nearest_  node